# Converting an old windows base application (with fox pro) to web base application (asp.net with c# csharp)-which technologies are needed(ajax or etc)?

Tags: asp.net, windows, ajax, performance, web-applications

my programming language is asp.net with c#...

i am looking for a best and **fastest** way for converting an old windows base application (with fox pro) to web base application (with asp.net and c#)...

in this case **speed** of inputing data is so important for users ...

which technology should i use for this purpose ?

i know ajax (update panel or RadAjaxManager) , is it enough for doing this or should i learn the other technologies ?

it seems this site has a good rating for working in ajax mode (like comments , voting and etc) is it possible to tell us about that?

in my country the max bandwith of my users is : 1mbps

thanks in advance

/best regards/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site uses several nice features of ajax and also Comet, which is ajax push. It keeps the connection between the server and client open for transfer of data from the server to the client. (Like the update that others have posted an answer while you are writing an answer). Also, I converted a project that was originally done on a text-based unix platform, to .net. The most important take-home lesson from that was, the users were used to working fast and not using a mouse and such.
Use .net, but consider what your users liked about the old application, and play in to that.
Cosider how they are used to interacting with the application and replicate that.
One of the things I did on that conversion project is make the enter key move the focus to the next input field. That allowed the users to work more like they were used to.

Comment: several nice features of ajax and also Comet => would you plz explain more!

Comment: Here are several resources about Comet (and other ajax-push implementations): http://retkomma.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/server-to-client-notification-using-asp-net-and-comet-approach/ http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/ http://pokein.codeplex.com/

Comment: would u plz link me a little project for implementation comments in stackoverflow - man this is fantastic - i though i should use timer for update comments and i know this is not a good way - can pokein library do this job?

Comment: I have not used pokein yet. I was just doing research for a future project for a client.