# updating data in a grid or something like that when someone inputs new data !(WITHOUT ANY POSTBACKS)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer, postback

imagine that i have a web page in my application for inputing data and there is a grid at the bottom of them (showing inputing data)...

i want to force this web page acts like a windows application (mean i do not want any postback after enter and that grid should be updated after inputing data without postback)...

imagine that i opened this page in my pc and my friend has opened this page too / i want when i input data in ajax mode , that grid updated for my friend without any postback / like windows application ...

is timer a good idea for doing this ?

or is there a better way for doing that?

thanks in advance

best regards

Comment: You might want to search for jquery Templates in asp.net... http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely going to have to go AJAX for this - the simplest (but definitely not the most efficient) method would be to add the AJAX Control Toolkit to your project, wrap your [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) in an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx), and have a timer on the page to check the database to see if there's anything newer than last time you checked.  If there has been a change, you can either re-databind the grid or just render that new content manually (and update the UpdatePanel).

Comment: thanks for answers / is it better simulation timer with jquery or timer is ok? / and what about update panel and ajax() in Jquery (which one?)

Comment: The advantage to using jQuery is the end result - less javascript, less http requests, and better performance overall.  But what you'll have to do is have either an ASP.NET Timer whose tick triggers an update to the UpdatePanel, or a jQuery timer whose tick calls a jQuery AJAX function (.ajax(), .get(), etc.), which gets data from a server-side function you write.  It's all about performance here - the time you'll have to have to put in for the jQuery method will pay off in performance.

Comment: plz check out this related link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488231/converting-an-old-windows-base-application-with-fox-pro-to-web-base-application